# How Can I Know If An Airport/ Airfield Is Equipped To Operate During A Power Outage

Tags: air-traffic-control, safety, military, flight-planning

My buddy was asked this by an IP. Is there a way to see in any publication that an airport is equipped to operate during a power outage? Or a way to see if a airfield has backup power?

Comment: Please include the location or legal jurisdiction and avoid less common or regional acronyms (such as IP) in questions.

Comment: IP is Internet Protocol. Also IP MAN is great at Kang Fu. Maybe IP means Instructor Pilot who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lighting at least, it will be listed in the AIP:

[image]

You can pretty much assume all aerodromes have backup power for stuff like ATC-equipment etc.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your time. It makes sense that basically everywhere is equipped with some sort of backup power.